# How to find location of Qt include headers on Linux

Tags: linux, qt, visual-studio-code

I just spent ages trying to find the location of the header files for Qt, so that I can properly configure VSCode to work with my Qt application. I couldn't find any answers on this website, so I'm posting here for how to find them.

Where are the Qt include headers on Linux?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can run:

```
qmake -query QT_INSTALL_HEADERS
```

This will return the location of the Qt header files, e.g for me: `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5`.